# How can Java represent very small fractional numbers?

Tags: java, floating-point

I made an application to detect spam mail using Naive Bayes classifier.

When estimating some probabilities the results are very small numbers, so java returns zero (0.0).

The variables are declared as float. How can Java handle very small numbers like 6.9e-232 ?

Comment: If the problem is just displaying the values, you can try `printf()`.

Comment: [Use](http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal:_A_Tutorial) [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: Java doubles can represent numbers as small as 2.2e-308 (approx), so I suspect you're doing something wrong.

Comment: He's using floats, not doubles, @Mike, so your suggestion would make a good answer, assuming double's range is actually wide enough for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you go from `float` to `double`, multiplying many "small" numbers will eventually underflow to zero. Use logarithms for the multiplication instead.

That is, since log(a*b) = log(a)+log(b), compute the product of a*b*c*...*z as

```
product = exp(log(a) + log(b) + log(c) + ... + log(z))
```

This will protect you from underflow.

Answer (score 4):

Change from `float` to `double`. This will give you numbers down to about 2.2e-308 before precision decreases.

Also, reconsider whether you need to handle numbers this small. If the probability of something is 6.9e-232, it is not likely it will occur in your lifetime.

Comment: Yeah, from my experience with Bayes, any probability below about 1% is likely irrelevant.

Comment: If you have a word with only one appearene???

Comment: @jimmysnn: A word with only one appearance does not have a probability anywhere near 6.9e-232. If all seven billion humans each run a billion computers producing a billion words per second for a billion years, that’s only 2.2e44 words.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest floating point double precision number there is, is equal to: 2^(−1074). This is equal to approximately: 4.94 × 10^(−324). Since you mentioned that you are using floats instead of doubles, the smallest single precision floating point number is: 2^(-382), which is approximately equal to: 1.01 × 10^(-115). So if your application concludes that the probabilities are smaller than that, then you have probably a bug in your calculations and not with the numbers itself.